# Add drop shadow to PNG using Cocoa

Tags: iphone, ipad, png, dropshadow

I have some PNGs with transparent backgrounds that I would like to add shadows to programatically. I've seen examples of adding shadows to square objects, but haven't seen any with complex shapes.

So the two steps I think I'd have to do would be:

- Isolate the PNG shape
- Draw a shape behind the PNG that is blurred, faded, and offset.

I don't have much experience with drawing within Cocoa, so any insight on where to begin would be much appreciated!

Screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [iworkinprogress.com](http://www.iworkinprogress.com/images/pngExample.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to call `CGContextSetShadow` in your `drawRect:` before you draw the images.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)invalidRect
{
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShadow(c, CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f), 5.0f);
    [myImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(50.0f, 50.0f)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this category to be very useful: UIImage+Shadow.m

https://gist.github.com/kompozer/387210

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a graphics person, but what about this: if you have a mask for these images, or if you can create one programatically, then you can probably use a blur function to add a shadow like effect.

Experiment in Photoshop/Acorn/Pixelmator?

Comment: Trying to do it programmatically, so that when they're rotated in the app they appear to have the same light source.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want shadows like they all have the same light source... it seems like you might actually be better off with an OpenGL view, that casts a light from above and the images would sit slightly above a flat plane to cast a shadow on.  I'd look for 3D OpenGL frameworks that would let you add things pretty easily...