# iOS drop shadow PNG animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, png, shadow

I have a PNG image of pedal in my view with transparency. I have implemented shadow according to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168813/add-drop-shadow-to-png-using-cocoa) question, using Swift. Here I have custom UIViewWithShadow:

```
import UIKit

class UIViewWithShadow: UIView {

    let image: UIImage!
    var shadowOffset = CGSize.init(width: 5, height: 5)
    var shadowBlur: CGFloat = 5

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetShadow(c, shadowOffset, shadowBlur);
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(c, shadowOffset, shadowBlur, UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8).CGColor)
        self.image.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(rect.minX, rect.minY)
    }
}
```

[Example of shadow change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hAWi.jpg)

It draws correctly, and now I need to animate that shadow - specificly, to decrease shadow's blur and offset when my image is pressed. I wonder if there is a way to do that like it is usually done with layer's shadow animation?

UPD

The goal is to make an illusion of pressing the pedal. I have done 3D transformation of it, the only thing I need is decreasing shadow under it, to make it look like the pedal became closer to the floor. If there are other ways to achieve that (like making shadow dependent on the Z-coordinate of pedal's view), I'll appreciate that

Comment: I'm not sure with Swift, but with Objective-C I would go at it with something like transitionWithView method.

Comment: I see you have some color changes and in pedal itself. As for me the simplest way to animate this all - it's use the images set. Like in this example http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-animation-uiimageview/

Comment: @JohnnyRockex, as far as I know, that shadow can be added only from the inside of the overridden _drawRect_ method. So where should I place the _transitionWithView_ method, and what should be it's _animation_ block content? If you have faced that, share some details, please

Comment: @Igor creating a sequence of frames for animation is a kind of cheating, I will come to that only if there is no other elegant solution=) I have animated everything I needed, except that shadow

Comment: Aside: common coding style for your `CGSize` initialization is `CGSizeMake(5, 5)`.

Comment: Aside: since the `image` is optional, you may want to chance access to it … `self.image?.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(rect.minX, rect.minY))`